# Angular 5 continue iteration, when we get response

Tags: async-await, angular5, httpclient, delay

I have a situation. I have a for loop. I am sending each object information to service and getting response back from the service.

I want to pause the for loop and continue once the http client return the response.  Here is my service code :

### .ts file

```
 for (var j = 0, counter = 0; j < this.actualObj.length; j++) {

    this._custService.placingSingleOrder(this.actualObj[j], this.headerInfo).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                counter++;

                if (data.status == "success") {
                    this.sucessOrders.push(data.inserted_order_id);
                    console.log('order inserted success fully........');
                    // this.toastr.success('Order Submitted Succefully !', 'Success!');

                } else if (data.status == "failure") {


                    // this.toastr.error('Order is already present in the database. Please check and try again!', 'Oopssssss!');
                }

                if (counter == this.actualObj.length) {

                    this.updateStatus();

                }
            },
            (error) => {
                counter++
                if (counter == this.actualObj.length) {

                    this.updateStatus();

                }
                //  this.loader = false;
                console.log(error);
            }
        );



    }
```

### Service method :

```
 placingSingleOrder(obj, headerInfo) {


    let api_token = sessionStorage.getItem('api_token');
    let email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
    console.log('before calling serviccccce', headerInfo);
    this.singleOrderHeader = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'apitoken': headerInfo.apitoken,
            //'apitoken': 'fkjdhsfhbdsabf',
            'customer_id': headerInfo.customer_id,
            'order_id': headerInfo.order_id
        })


    };
    console.log('before calling serviccccce', this.singleOrderHeader);
    return this.http.post(apiServicesURL + 'api/restapi/Order/addMwwOrder', JSON.stringify({ token: api_token, email: email, Order: obj }), this.singleOrderHeader).map((response: any) => {
        console.log("single order response is: ", response);
        return response;

    });

}
```

So, once the first iteration gives response, then the second iteration should start. Point me out with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **recursive function** call instead for loop, watch after each success and then call function again, Set one base case (i.e. call recursively unless and until it reaches to end of loop)

Try this:

```
const j = this.actualObj.length; // set it global
recursiveFunction(this.j) {
  this._custService
  .placingSingleOrder(this.actualObj[this.j], this.headerInfo)
  .subscribe(data => {
    // your code handler after each success

    this.j--; // decrease operator and call recursive function
    if(this.j) {
      this.recursiveFunction(this.j);
    }
  }, error => {
    // error handler
  })
}
```